# Oracle Procedure Errors PLS-00330, ORA-00904: : invalid identifier, and Error(37,24): PLS-00382

Tags: database, cursor, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure

I am trying to create a procedure which populates data from one table to another. If the combination of columns exists, then two columns in the target table are updated. If combination of columns doesn't exist, then a record is created or overwritten in the target table.

Can someone/anyone please help me resolve the errors mentioned? I will be beholden to you.

Here is the procedure.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE           "PRO_1_Table_2_another" AS

CURSOR C1_CUR IS
SELECT    D.D1
          ,SUBSTR(SISR.S1,1,4)
          ,SISR.S2
          ,SISR.S3
          ,SISR.S4
          ,SISR.S5
          ,SISR.S6
          ,SISR.S7
          ,SISR.S8
          ,SISR.S9
    FROM  something_in_system_record SISR
         ,Dump D
    WHERE SUBSTR(SISR.A1,1,4)=D.D1;

    TYPE C1_TA is table of C1_CUR%ROWTYPE;
    V_C1 C1_TA;

  BEGIN


   FOR i in C1_CUR LOOP

   V_C1 := C1_TA; --Error(26,12): PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
          MERGE INTO In_something TGT
          USING
          (SELECT V_C1(i).A1 AS  A1,
                  V_C1(i).A2 AS  A2,
                  V_C1(i).A3 AS  A3,
                  V_C1(i).A4 AS  A4,
                  V_C1(i).A5 AS  A5,
                  V_C1(i).A6 AS  A6,
                  V_C1(i).A7 AS  A7,
                  V_C1(i).A8 AS  A8,
                  V_C1(i).A9 AS  A9 --Error(37,19): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: :invalid identifier &&& Error(37,24): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
          FROM DUAL) SRC
          ON     (SRC.A1 = TGT.A1
              AND SRC.A2 = TGT.A2
              AND SRC.A3 = TGT.A3
              AND SRC.A4 = TGT.A4
              AND SRC.A5 = TGT.A5
              AND SRC.A6 = TGT.A6
              AND SRC.A7 = TGT.A7
          )
          WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET TGT.A8 = SRC.A8,
                       TGT.A9 = SRC.A9
          WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT (TGT.A1
               ,TGT.A2
               ,TGT.A3
               ,TGT.A4
               ,TGT.A5
               ,TGT.A6
               ,TGT.A7
               ,TGT.A8
               ,TGT.A9)   
          VALUES 
              (SRC.S1
              ,SRC.S2
              ,SRC.S3
              ,SRC.S4
              ,SRC.S5
              ,SRC.S6
              ,SRC.S7
              ,SRC.S8
              ,SRC.S9);          
     END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
   EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE||' - '||SQLERRM);
END PRO_1_Table_2_another;
```

Comment: I have updated my question indicating where the errors are generated.

Comment: You seem to be mixing A1 and S1 etc., are they all actually the same in both tables?

Answer (score 0):

The `ORA-00904: : invalid identifier` comes when you miss spelled the column name.

Like you have a table `Employee` that have the following column.

```
|ID|Name|Address|
```

and you write a DML statement like this,

```
select * from Employee where Adress like '%abcpqr%'
```

Then it will throw this exception.  `ORA-00904: : invalid identifier`

Hope it will help.

Comment: I checked all the columns. They are not misspelled. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `C1_TA` type is a collection, so

```
V_C1 := C1_TA;
```

should be:

```
V_C1 := C1_TA();
```

... but you don't need it; you're mixing up different cursor types. You seem to have written part of it as if you were bulk collecting into your table type, and then using `i` as an index; but here `i` is a record type. You don't need your table type at all, or the variable instance of it.

You also haven't added a column alias for `SUBSTR(SISR.S1,1,4)` so referring to `S1` later  isn't valid; and you've mixed up the A1/S1 names in a few places, which may be from manually changing the names of your real columns to hide them (which is fine, but do it consistently).

So correcting all of that you'd get:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE           "PRO_1_Table_2_another" AS

CURSOR C1_CUR IS
SELECT    D.D1
          ,SUBSTR(SISR.S1,1,4) AS S1
          ,SISR.S2
          ,SISR.S3
          ,SISR.S4
          ,SISR.S5
          ,SISR.S6
          ,SISR.S7
          ,SISR.S8
          ,SISR.S9
    FROM  something_in_system_record SISR
         ,Dump D
    WHERE SUBSTR(SISR.S1,1,4)=D.D1;

  BEGIN

   FOR i in C1_CUR LOOP

          MERGE INTO In_something TGT
          USING
          (SELECT i.S1 AS  A1,
                  i.S2 AS  A2,
                  i.S3 AS  A3,
                  i.S4 AS  A4,
                  i.S5 AS  A5,
                  i.S6 AS  A6,
                  i.S7 AS  A7,
                  i.S8 AS  A8,
                  i.S9 AS  A9
          FROM DUAL) SRC
          ON     (SRC.A1 = TGT.A1
              AND SRC.A2 = TGT.A2
              AND SRC.A3 = TGT.A3
              AND SRC.A4 = TGT.A4
              AND SRC.A5 = TGT.A5
              AND SRC.A6 = TGT.A6
              AND SRC.A7 = TGT.A7
          )
          WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET TGT.A8 = SRC.A8,
                       TGT.A9 = SRC.A9
          WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT (TGT.A1
               ,TGT.A2
               ,TGT.A3
               ,TGT.A4
               ,TGT.A5
               ,TGT.A6
               ,TGT.A7
               ,TGT.A8
               ,TGT.A9)   
          VALUES 
              (SRC.A1
              ,SRC.A2
              ,SRC.A3
              ,SRC.A4
              ,SRC.A5
              ,SRC.A6
              ,SRC.A7
              ,SRC.A8
              ,SRC.A9);          
     END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
   EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE||' - '||SQLERRM);
END "PRO_1_Table_2_another";
/
```

... but you're doing a separate merge for each row you find in your cursor, which doesn't really make sense. You can just do:

```
MERGE INTO In_something TGT
USING (
    SELECT D.D1
          ,SUBSTR(SISR.S1,1,4) AS S1
          ,SISR.S2
          ,SISR.S3
          ,SISR.S4
          ,SISR.S5
          ,SISR.S6
          ,SISR.S7
          ,SISR.S8
          ,SISR.S9
    FROM  something_in_system_record SISR
    JOIN  Dump D
    ON    SUBSTR(SISR.S1,1,4)=D.D1
    ) SRC
ON  (
        SRC.S1 = TGT.A1
    AND SRC.S2 = TGT.A2
    AND SRC.S3 = TGT.A3
    AND SRC.S4 = TGT.A4
    AND SRC.S5 = TGT.A5
    AND SRC.S6 = TGT.A6
    AND SRC.S7 = TGT.A7
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET TGT.A8 = SRC.S8,
             TGT.A9 = SRC.S9
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (TGT.A1
     ,TGT.A2
     ,TGT.A3
     ,TGT.A4
     ,TGT.A5
     ,TGT.A6
     ,TGT.A7
     ,TGT.A8
     ,TGT.A9)   
VALUES 
    (SRC.S1
    ,SRC.S2
    ,SRC.S3
    ,SRC.S4
    ,SRC.S5
    ,SRC.S6
    ,SRC.S7
    ,SRC.S8
    ,SRC.S9);
```

... which should do the same thing; and you can still stick that inside a procedure if you want. It's usually not considered a good idea to commit inside a procedure, but you may have a legitimate reason to do that.

Comment: @Alex....Thank you, Sire! 

May the roof above you never fall in,
And those gathered beneath it never fall out.
- Irish Proverb (read it somewhere)